# Handle unknown content-type of response with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, content-type, alamofire

I use `Alamofire` to do requests to a rest service. If the request is successful the server returns a `JSON` with content-type `application/json`. But if the request fails the server returns a simple `String`.

So, I don't know how to handle on it with `Alamofire`, because I don't know how the response look like. I need a solution to handle on the different response types.

This code I can use to handle on a successful request:

```
request(.POST, wholeUrl, parameters: parameters, encoding: .Custom(encodingClosure))
            //.validate()
        .responseJSON {
            (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

                //check if error is returned
                if (error == nil) {
                    //this crashes if simple string is returned
                    JSONresponse = JSON(object: data!)
                }
```

And this code I can use to handle on failed request:

```
    request(.POST, wholeUrl, parameters: parameters, encoding: .Custom(encodingClosure))
            //.validate()
        .responseString {
            (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

                //check if error is returned
                if (error == nil) {
                    responseText = data!
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem:

```
request(.POST, wholeUrl, parameters: parameters, encoding: .Custom(encodingClosure))
    .validate()
.response {
    (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

        //check if error is returned
        if (error == nil) {
            var serializationError: NSError?
            let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data! as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &serializationError)

            JSONresponse = JSON(object: json!)
        }
        else {
             //this is the failure case, so its a String
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't specify the response type, and don't comment out the `.validate()`.
Check for error, and then proceed accordingly

```
request(.POST, wholeUrl, parameters: parameters, encoding: .Custom(encodingClosure))
        .validate()
    .response {
        (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

            //check if error is returned
            if (error == nil) {
                //this is the success case, so you know its JSON
                //response = JSON(object: data!)
            }
            else {
                 //this is the failure case, so its a String
            }
     }
```

Comment: I tried it, but how can I convert the `data` to `JSON(object:data)` or to a `String`? I have to analyse the response data to do the next steps in my code.

Comment: You don't have to analyse the response data, just check for the error. I have edited the answer.

Comment: In the success case I do `response = JSON(object: data!)`. But `response` is `null` after that. `data` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

If you are expecting `JSON` on *success* and a `String` on *error*, you should call the `.validate()` hook and try parsing the response data as a string if the request fails.

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

...

Alamofire.request("http://domain/endpoint", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
        if let error = response.error {
            if let data = response.data, let errMsg = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Error string from server: \(errMsg)")
            } else {
                print("Error message from Alamofire: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } 
        guard let data = response.result.value else {
            print("Unable to parse response data")
            return
        }
        print("JSON from server: \(JSON(data))")
    })
```